# ismember() does not return enough elements

Tags: matlab

Consider the following example code:

```
spacing_Pin  = transpose(-27:0.001:2); 
Phi_intrp3   = interp1(P_in3,Phi_out_deg3,spacing_Pin,'spline');

size(P_in3) = size(Phi_out_deg3) = 40   1

P_in1st = P_in3 -0.76;
thetah_1st = Phi_intrp3(ismember(spacing_Pin,P_in1st));
```

I think `thetah_1st`should now have 40 elements. It turns out, however, it only has 20. This must be, because `P_in1st`can only be found 20 times in `spacing_Pin`. I know, you're not given `P_in3`, but it only has up to 2 digits after the dot. So should `P_in1st`. `min(P_in3) =  -25.9800`and `max(P_in3) = -0.0200`. These values should be included in `spacing_Pin`. Why does `thetah_1st` have only 20 entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to say without more information and your actual variable values, but I suspect that the issue is with using `ismember` the way that you have.

Since you are looking for floating point numbers within an array rather than integers, you should use [`ismembertol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismembertol.html) (`ismember` with a tolerance) to handle any potential floating point errors.

```
thetah_1st = Phi_intrp3(ismembertol(spacing_Pin, P_in1st));
```

Comment: you're right Suever, it is working when I use ismembertol. I assume ismembertol is using the eps tolerance by default? .. when I change the 4th code line to `P_in1st = P_in3 + 0.0053`the resulting `thetah_1st`is an empty matrix. I was trying to fix this problem by choosing a spacing of 0.0001 in the first code line. Hence my other question that you commented on. The problem is not solved by changing the spacing, however. Sorry that i cannot upload the whole variable lists. But I can upload an excerpt, if that would help

Comment: You can specify a custom tolerance if you want as a third input. Those details are specific to your other question so you can likely go ahead and close/accept this one

Comment: ok, thx. Well, I made my comment a new question. It is very similar to this one, however.

Comment: @Luk Wait, what? Just modify your *other* question where you're modifying the step size to be more clear. No need to ask yet another question